# Loop for on KnexJS

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, knex.js

I'm trynna loop into a Knex.js query in order to hash all users passwords.
I wrote this:

```
return knex.select().from('UTILISATEUR')
    .then(function(result) {
        for (let i=0; i < result.length; i++){
          pwdToHash = result[i].MOTPASS;
          const hashedPwd = bcrypt.hashSync(pwdToHash,salt);
                    return knex('UTILISATEUR')
                    .where({NOGENE: result[i].NOGENE})
                    .update(
                    {MOTPASS: hashedPwd},['NOGENE', 'MOTPASS']
                    );
        }
    });
```

But he just changes the first line, and then goes out the loop, is there anything wrong?

Edit:
I fixed it buy using **await**:

```
return knex.select().from('UTILISATEUR')
    .then(async function(result) {
        for (let i=0; i < result.length; i++){
          let pwdToHash = result[i].MOTPASS;
          const hashedPwd = bcrypt.hashSync(pwdToHash,salt);
          console.log(hashedPwd)
          await knex('UTILISATEUR')
            .where({NOGENE: result[i].NOGENE})
            .update(
              {MOTPASS: hashedPwd},['NOGENE', 'MOTPASS']
            );
        }
    });
```

Comment: what if you use `let pwdToHash` ?

Comment: It doesnt work..

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `return` in the `for` loop, so after the first iteration, it will exit the loop.

```
return knex.select().from('UTILISATEUR')
    .then(function(result) {
        for (let i=0; i < result.length; i++){
          pwdToHash = result[i].MOTPASS;
          const hashedPwd = bcrypt.hashSync(pwdToHash,salt);
          knex('UTILISATEUR')
            .where({NOGENE: result[i].NOGENE})
            .update(
              {MOTPASS: hashedPwd},['NOGENE', 'MOTPASS']
            );
        }
    });
```

Comment: In this answer those update queries are never even sent to the database...

Answer (score 0):

to not mixup promise and async/await syntax so much and to return those updated rows it could be written for example like this:

```
const result = await knex.select().from('UTILISATEUR');    
const ret = [];

for (const row of result) {
  let pwdToHash = row.MOTPASS;
  const hashedPwd = bcrypt.hashSync(pwdToHash,salt);
  console.log(hashedPwd)
  ret.push_back(await knex('UTILISATEUR')
    .where({NOGENE: row.NOGENE}).update({
      MOTPASS: hashedPwd
    }, ['NOGENE', 'MOTPASS']));
}

return ret;
```